# how to return first element in multiple tuples as keys in dictionary

Tags: python

For example, if

```
a = {('a','b','c'):2, ('b','c','d'):3}
```

I want to return only `'a','b'`.

I tried:

```
for key in a:

    return key[0]
```

but it only returned `'a'`.

Is there a proper way of finding first element without using lambda or counter or stuff like that (this is a basic course in python). So, no other input program.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're after. What is the value you would expect it to return?

Comment: I understand that, I meant 'b' on the other tuple, return only the first element in multiple tuples.

Comment: Matthew Adams solution should do it then.

Comment: I would use `yield` instead of `return`. Note that the function then will return not a list but an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

The function (and therefore your `for` loop) ends as soon as it hits `return`. You should store the values in a list and then return that. Something like:

```
def getFirstElems(dic):
    firstElems = []
    for key in dic:
        firstElems.append(key[0])
    return firstElems
```

Then if you run that function like this:

```
a = {('a','b','c'):2, ('b','c','d'):3}
elem1, elem2 = getFirstElems(a)
print "elem1:", elem1
print "elem2:", elem2
```

You get this output:

```
elem1: a
elem2: b
```

Comment: This works definitely but I need without these first element without using making new list because my assignment has much more tuple then this.

Comment: @EricJung Exactly what is your desired output?

Comment: 'a', 'b' rather than ['a','b'] a,b as string not inside the list

Comment: @EricJung: If you can't use a temporary list/tuple, than making the function into a generator is the solution. But unless you have millions of items, you can use a list/tuple.

Comment: You can return a list and grab each element in one line. (I updated my answer to show this.) Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @EricJung Still unclear whether you're looking for a string, tuple, generator, or any other possible combination of two characters. If a list isn't sufficient, you need to let people know what is.

Comment: @EricJung: Multiple items must be returned in some kind of container. If you want `'a', 'b' ` combined together into a single string (a container of characters), just change the last line in the function to  `return ''.join(firstElems)`.

Answer (score 2):

do you want something like this

```
In [4]: a = {('a','b','c'):2, ('b','c','d'):3}

In [5]: [key[0] for key in a.keys()]
Out[5]: ['a', 'b']
```

The problem with your code is the `return` statement... you should hold all the results before returning...

if you want individual elements every time you can use `generators`

```
In [19]: def mygenerator():
   ....:     a = {('a','b','c'):2, ('b','c','d'):3}
   ....:     for k in a.keys():
   ....:         yield k[0]
   ....:

In [20]: mg = mygenerator()

In [21]: print(mg)
<generator object mygenerator at 0x035FA148>

In [22]: for i in mg:
   ....:     print i
   ....:
a
b
```

Comment: I am after the first element in the tuple 1 (key1) which is 'a' and first element in the tuple 2 (key2) which is 'b'. So it should return 'a','b' rather than ['a','b'] without the list;;;

Answer (score -1):

from what i can tell you want to loop over the keys of the dict.  try

```
for k in a.keys():
```

Comment: I tried  for k in a.keys():

        return k[0] but it still returns only 'a'

Comment: OK i think i misunderstood what you were originally trying to do.  look at Matthew Adams solution

Comment: `for k in a:` does the same thing as `for k in a.keys()`